# How to stop the program itself?

Tags: android

I'm writing method which checks own version of program. If program's version old, then program need stop itself. How can I stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: This is not recommended, as it can leave Android in an unexpected state.

Answer (score 4):

You probably search for `finish()`.